# How to split a group of sentence into json format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

I'm having a hard time to split the sentence. This is an example of data

> 1. Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle.
> 2. Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade.

The result that I want it to be in JSON format.

```
{id: "1", text: "Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle."},
{id: "2", text: "Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade."}
```

**The problem**
I don't know how to detect strings and split them correctly or using regex. Because some of data have a number such as 50. in the middle of the sentence and make it wrong data to split. And the number can be up to 4 digits and follow by "." make it harder to detect and split.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is every sentence on new line?

Comment: Every input string is starting with a number followed by dot and then a space, correct?

Comment: No Some sentences having multiple new lines in one sentence. and yes every query will start with number and full stop and 1 whitespace character same as example above.

Comment: Can a sentence contain numbers followed by a dot, e.g. _"1. Shopping list 1. A 2. B 3. C 2. Second sentence"_?

Comment: Yes. in some sentence have number and followed by a dot.

Comment: In that case it's not possible. Different results are possible. E.g. `[{ id: 1, text: 'Shopping list 1. A' }, { id: 2, text: 'B' }, { id: 3, text: 'C 2. Second sentence' }]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the provided text is one large string.

```js
const text = `\
1. Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle.
2. Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade.
`;
```

You can split the string into sentences by using the regex `/^(?=\d+\. )/m`. Here the `^` in combination with the `m` flag will target the beginning of a line, `(?=)` is a look ahead, to not remove the matched characters from the result. In the look ahead you'll find `\d+` (one or more digits) followed by `\.` (the dot character) followed by   (a space). Thus matching all beginnings of lines if they are immediately followed by a number, dot and space.

```js
const sentences = text.split(/^(?=\d+\. )/m);
//=> [
//   "1. Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle.\n",
//   "2. Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade.\n"
// ]
```

The next step is separating the number from the rest of the sentence and creating an object with the two parts. For this we could use the regex `/(\d+)\. (.*)/s`. This places the starting digits in capture group 1. It then matches a dot and a space, and places everything after it in capture group 2. `.*` normally doesn't match newline characters, however by providing the `s` flag it does. The `s` flag is relatively new and if you can't use it yet you can replace `.*` with `[^]*`. `[\S\s]*` is also often used as a replacement.

```js
const items = sentences.map((sentence) => {
  const [_match, id, text] = sentence.match(/(\d+)\. (.*)/s);
  return { id, text };
});
//=> [{
//   id: "1",
//   text: "Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle.\n"
// }, {
//   id: "2",
//   text: "Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade.\n"
// }]
```

Note that `text` may include multiple lines, if you want to compact whitespace beforehand use the the following instead.

```js
return { id, text: text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim() }
```

Which matches one or more whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, vertical-tabs, etc.) and replaces it with a single space. `trim()` then removes possible whitespace at the start and end of the string.

```js
const text = `\
1. Go to the dining room. Click on the cabinet to take the whisky bottle.
2. Go to the kitchen. Click on the fridge. Jason gets a lemonade.
`;

const sentences = text.split(/^(?=\d+\. )/m);

const items = sentences.map((sentence) => {
  const [_match, id, text] = sentence.match(/(\d+)\. (.*)/s);
  return { id, text: text.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim() };
});

console.log(items);
```

---

This answer assumes that `text` starts with a number (one or more digits), dot and space. If the start of `text` doesn't conform to this pattern `sentence.match(/(\d+)\. (.*)/s)` will return either `null` or start half way into the sentence for the first sentence.

You could kick the first sentence in this scenario by doing the following after splitting the sentence.

```js
if (!text.match(/^\d+ /)) sentences.shift();
```

Alternatively you could replace `split()` with `match()` to search for sentences that do match the pattern, skipping the first bit of text that doesn't.

```js
const sentences = text.match(/^\d+\. (\D|(?!^)\d|\d(?!\. ))*/gm);
```

Which matches a number (one or more digits), dot and space at the start of line. Followed by zero or more characters that match the following criteria: non-digit, digit if not at the start of a line, digit if not followed by a dot and a space.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat excellent. Before I try I want to ask you first why need backslash at the first letter of string?

Comment: The backslash in ``const text = `\`` is to ignore the newline character directly after it. Without the backslash `text` would be `"\n1. …"` with the backslash `text` is `"1. …"`. The alternative would be to place the first sentence on the same line as the start of the string literal. eg. `const text = \`1. …`. However this ultimately doesn't really matter since I don't think you define `text` yourself. It is probably the contents of a file, a web-request or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try.

```
const fun = (str) => {
   let i = 0;
   let index = '';
   while (true) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 57) {
        index = `${index}${str.charAt(i)}`;
        i += 1;
    } else {
        break;
    }
   }
   return {id: index, text: str.slice(i + 1).trim()}
}

const ans1 = fun(`109. Go to the dining room. Click on the 23. cabinet to take the whisky bottle`);
const ans2 = fun(`19. Go to the kitchen. cabinet to take the whisky bottle45.`);
console.log(ans1, ans2)
```

For every input string you can run the above function to get the result.

Comment: Thank you. Your solutions kinda works. But if I want to detect new line also. How can I do? At least if I  will manually fix the sentence that have multiple new line myself. But I don't want to do that 1000 times for every single sentence.

Comment: On which condition you want to differentiate the individual input strings. I mean, if the string is: '109. Go to the dining room. Click on the 23. cabinet to take the whisky bottle', then whether you will assume it single string or 2 strings (one starting with 109. and another starting with 23.)? What u will expect here?

Comment: The solution that I can think is if I have these 1000 sentences. I just run the index count as 1 and run into 1000. if index is not equal to the string that detect such as "click on the 23.". 23 is not index 109, right? It will not split that "23." in the last sentence. But kinda convoluted for me to do.

Comment: That's ok my friend but what if the input is like this
1. This is a string. 2. that has 10 letters.
here the problem comes, will u assume it as just one string or two

Comment: I read all the data. No number that count to next index in one sentence. (example: "1. click on the 2.").